# Are there customizable vertical side bars available in i3?

Tags: i3, toolbar

I currently use Polybar as my main and only tool bar for i3.

What I like about it, is that it's highly customizable:

- the look and feel can be customized at will to have a slick and modern look
- I can have almost any monitoring tool based on scripts (CPU, GPU activities, RAM, etc.)
- The bar is interactive: I can click on it to change workspace, logout, lock the screen, etc.

However, as far as I know, the bar can only be placed at the top or the bottom of the desktop. When you use a 16/9 display, vertical space is precious.

Is there a way to display the bar on the side? If not, are there other customizable bars similar to polybar to do that?

Comment: Here's a list of about 20 other status bars you can use instead of Polybar: https://github.com/kimond/awesome-statusbars ; Not sure exactly which one allows verticle but I know I've seen people do it before.

Comment: Very interesting link indeed. After a first quick look, none of them seem to be capable of vertical orientation

Comment: The problem with a vertical status bar is that you can't fit the words unless you have them sideways/vertical as well, like this person did: https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/b0a2rd/dwm_feeling_cute/ ; they used lemonbar.

Comment: I was thinking about doing like here, but in i3 https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/anp51q/awesome_material_awesome_workflow/

Comment: Dzen says it offers vertical menu mode. Scroll down to (3) Menu here: https://github.com/robm/dzen ; no pics though so not sure how it looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tint2 should cover you needs. It can be placed vertically.